# Blazor Virtualize not displaying anything

Tags: .net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

I'm attempting to use the Virtualize feature of blazor which appears in all the documentation I can find as trivially simple. However, when I run the below code, the foreach displays as expected, but the Virtualize doesn't display anything. I'm attempting to do this with .NET 8.0 preview Web Application.

```
@page "/mypage"

<PageTitle>My Page</PageTitle>

<p>foreach</p>

<div style="height:100px;overflow-y:scroll">
    @foreach (string item in stringList)
    {
        <div>@item</div>
    }
</div>

<p>Virtualize</p>
<div style="height:100px;overflow-y:scroll">
    <Virtualize Items="@stringList">
        <div>@context</div>
    </Virtualize>
</div>

@code
{
    private List<string>? stringList;

    protected override void OnInitialized() =>stringList ??= new() { "Here's a string!", "Here's another string!" };
}
```

Here are the results I get:

[image: code result]

I have also attempted it with setting the context to a different name and adding placeholder content. All have resulted in nothing being displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the render mode attribute for the page. In .NET 8 Blazor you need to declare the render mode to enable interactivity. It seems like Virtualize is considered an interactive component.

```cs
@attribute [RenderModeAuto]
@page "/"

<PageTitle>My Page</PageTitle>

<p>foreach</p>

<div style="height:100px;overflow-y:scroll">
    @foreach (string item in stringList)
    {
        <div>@item</div>
    }
</div>

<p>Virtualize</p>
<div style="height:100px;overflow:auto;">
    <Virtualize Items="@stringList">
        <div style="color:red;"> something @context</div>
    </Virtualize>
</div>

@code
{
    private List<string>? stringList;

    protected override void OnInitialized() => stringList ??= new() { "Here's a string!", "Here's another string!", "Here's a string!", "Here's another string!", "Here's a string!", "Here's another string!", "Here's a string!", "Here's another string!" };
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!